# SQL count from same column but different conditions fetching later count result for all

Tags: sql

I am trying to count same column for different condition , but I am getting the later count result for the other conditions also.

For this sql :

```
select count(eqa.ID) as gold_yes  from EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa , EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa 
where esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID and eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'Yes' and   eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc';
```

I am getting the output `gold_yes:` `1`

Again if i run sql with different condition :

```
select count(eqa.ID) as gold_no  from EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa , EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa 
where esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID and eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'No' and  eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc';
```

I am getting the output `gold_no:` `0`

Now if the run sql combined :

```
select count(eqa.ID) as gold_yes ,count(eqa_2.ID) as gold_no  from EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa , EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa ,EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa_2 , EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa_2 
where esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID and eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'Yes' and   eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc'
and esa_2.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and esa_2.ID = eqa_2.SC_ID and eqa_2.QU_ANSWER = 'No' and eqa_2.QU_TYPE = 'abc';
```

I am getting the output : `gold_yes:` `0` and `gold_no:` `0` . Which should be `gold_yes:` `1` and `gold_no:` `0`

Can anybody please guide me what the mistake I am doing .

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` condition in your query are the problem: you can't have both `eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'Yes'` and `eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'No'`, so the query return 0 rows, and the count of the values of 0 rows is also 0.

You can change the condition to `OR`, or you can take the same condition in the `COUNT`, while doing that you should also change the query to use explicit `JOIN` instead of writing the join condition in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as gold_yes
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'No' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as gold_no
FROM   EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa
       INNER JOIN EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa ON esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID
WHERE  esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 
  AND  eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc';
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your conditions from the `where` clause into a `case` and sum it up

```
select sum(case when esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 
                     and eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'Yes' 
                     and eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc'
                then 1
                else 0
           end) as gold_yes
...
from EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa
join EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa on esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and 
                      esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID   and 
                      eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'Yes'and  
                      eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc') 
           THEN 1 END) AS eqacount1
       SUM(CASE WHEN (esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and 
                      esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID   and
                      eqa.QU_ANSWER = 'No' and 
                      eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc') 
          THEN 1 END)  AS eqacount2 
from EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa , EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa
```

:
it will work check it out

Regards,
Praveen Nelge

Comment: You've moved the join conditions in to the aggregate functions.  That's a really bad idea for performance.

Answer (score -1):

```
select count(case when eqa.QU_ANSWER='Yes' then eqa.ID end) as gold_yes,
       count(case when eqa.QU_ANSWER='No' then eqa.ID end) as gold_no
from   EC_SECTION_ANSWER esa , EC_QUESTION_ANSWER eqa 
where  esa.SC_NUMBER = 1079 and 
       esa.ID = eqa.SC_ID and 
       eqa.QU_TYPE = 'abc'
```